# Spiral Array with geometry nodes issue

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to spiral out some elements/bridges off a central column with geometry nodes.

This setup works for the most part but I get these two elements in a wrong position and rotation.

how can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Try vector math with $position * (1, 1, 0)$ instead of *Normal* node.

Comment: perfect thank you!